Remove popup illustration for R function in VScode
enter image description hereI am annoyed with the popup illustration for R function in VScode.
I have tried to add the following words to settings.json. It doesn't work at all. Is there another solution to suppress the pop-up?
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off",
    "editor.suggest.showInlineDetails": false,
    "editor.suggest.showStatusBar": true,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": "off",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
    "editor.suggest.matchOnWordStartOnly": false,
    "editor.suggest.selectionMode": "never",
    "editor.inlineSuggest.showToolbar": "never",
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggest.showReferences": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,


I added "editor.hover.enabled": false to settings.json, and it worked. The popup illustration for the R function is gone when the mouse gets close to the function.

Adding this to settings.json works:
"editor.hover.enabled": false,

There is also a lot of discussion of other options here in this Stack Overflow question: How can I disable hover tooltip hints in VS Code?
